# In the dart:io library, why would one want to set runInShell: true when calling Process.run?

Tags: shell, process, io, dart

What functionality does this offer? Furthermore, how does the process get called when runInShell is set to false? What's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create a new child process with your_executable or alternatively with `runInShell`, create a new child process with the shell executable and pass `-c your_executable` to make the shell create a new child process with `your_executable`. 
For example if you want to execute bash builtins or if you want to create a new environment for the new process with a specific `.bashrc` or if you have a script with a hashbang and want to shell figure out how to run that executable.

Comment: So for example if I were writing a shell in dart and I wanted to run the 'cd' command I could - instead of implementing the code to change a directory - spawn a bash process and use the built in 'cd' command of the bash shell instead?

Comment: The current working directory (cwd) is per process. The shell would be a new process and have its own cwd. When it returns back to the caller, the caller would not have the cwd changed.